# link copy plugin for firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-plugin, links

I need to copy links in the clipboard by clicking on them - one click, one copy. Is there possibility to do it with some Firefox plugin or something?

Comment: OOC, why isnt right clicking and selecting copy link not acceptable?

Comment: I think we have a classic example of an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341) here.
@fogbit: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Keltari: because i have billions of links, some of those i want to copy. And i would like to finish it before i die. This is why right click + copy link isn't acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to copy lots of links from a single page, try the [**Link Gopher**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/link-gopher/) add-on:

> Extracts all links from web page, sorts them, removes duplicates, and displays them in a new tab for inspection or copy and paste into other systems.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Simiar add-ons such as [Linkinator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/linkinator/) might also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [FireGestures plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firegestures/). The *Copy Location* is not enabled by default. I set it to *RL* which means you need to click the right button, move right, move left and release the button.

Btw. Using the other gestures is also pretty great :)

[image: FireGestures Settings]